# How to return matched value with .NET regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to capture **user.name** in PowerShell, using .NET regex, like this:

`Return ([regex]::Match($string,'"MYDOMAIN",Name="(?+")').Value)`

Example string to search:

```
$string = '\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain="MYDOMNAME",Name="user.name"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain="\\.\root:\,etc,etc'
```

I'm looking for the first occurrence of any **user.name** (if there happens to be more than one).

In English: return the pattern "MYDOMAIN",Name=" and any pattern after it that is made up of any character, repeated one or more times, up to the first " then stop.

The problem is I am getting everything until the LAST " in the string.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<="MYDOMNAME",Name=")[^"]+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22MYDOMNAME%22%2cName%3d%22)%5b%5e%22%5d%2b&i=%5c%5c.%5croot%5ccimv2%3aWin32_Account.Domain%3d%22MYDOMNAME%22%2cName%3d%22user.name%22%5c%5c.%5croot%5ccimv2%3aWin32_Account.Domain%3d%22%5c%5c.%5croot%3a%5c%2cetc%2cetc)

The lookbehind `(?<="MYDOMNAME",Name=")` makes sure there is `"MYDOMNAME",Name="` before the sequence of characters other than a double quote.

Your regex `"MYDOMAIN",Name="(?+")` is just not valid, it throws an *Unrecognized grouping construct* error because `(?...)` cannot be parsed as neither a capturing, nor a non-capturing, nor an atomic group.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  For my own understanding, could you briefly explain lookbehind ... how are they invoked?  are the parens simply defining a capture group?  is a capture group necessary with my previous syntax: `([regex]::Match($string,'"MYDOMAIN",Name="(?+")').Value)` namely the .Value operator?